# forEach loop check | AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
         // Check voted
            var votes = res.data.votes;

            if(votes.length == 0){$scope.like = true;}
            votes.forEach(function(vote){
                if(vote.userId === auth.profile.user_id) {
                    $scope.liked = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.like = true;
                }
            });
```

I have written a code to check if the user has voted or not, but I'm having a small issue with the else statement:

using the following code, the `$scope.liked` works correctly, but the else statement only goes for the first.
How can I edit this, so he goes through all the votes, and if nothing is found, he displays the `$scope.like`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about just do it outside the loop?

`votes.forEach(function(vote){
                if(vote.userId === auth.profile.user_id) {
                    $scope.liked = true;
                } 
            });
            $scope.like = !$scope.liked;`